# How to overlap lazy layout items in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-view, android-jetpack

i am trying to overlap first item in LazyVertivalGrid over second item but i have no idea how can i achieve it.

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(4),
    state = state,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    reverseLayout = false
) {
    items(
        key = { "$it + ${colors[it].value}" },
        count = colors.size,
        itemContent = { index ->
            val movable = remember {
                movableContentWithReceiverOf<SceneScope> {
                    MyElement(
                        isTransformed = isTransformed,
                        selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
                        currentIndex = index,
                        sceneScope = this
                    ) {
                        Box(
                            modifier =
                                Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                                    .padding(10.dp)
                                    .background(color = colors[index], RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                                    .clickable { selectedIndex.value = index }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

            movable()
        }
    )
}
```

[grid image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIxGo.png)

in the above image i am trying to overlap 5th indexed (6th element) item over 6th indexed (7th element) item
but instead of being in front of blue box its going behind it.

Edit 1 :- it is overlaping if i make reverse layout true, but i want the element to overlap both side elements.

Comment: Did you try increasing its zIndex? https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/ui/ui/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/ZIndexModifier.kt;l=41